# Nationality, does it matter in Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, voting, users

Yesterday, a Stack Exchange fellow commoner contacted me through my personal email address as an official representative of Stack Exchange. He tried to flatter me as the 800th "user" coming from Mexico, China, Nepal etc. and he asked me, in an indirect way, to vote for him in that silly cheese contest.

To my understanding Stack Exchange is a global community, nationality is irrelevant.

Should I denounce him to Stack Exchange community?

Comment: What is "fellow commoner"?

Comment: It's quite easy to get to your e-mail address using your profile. If you were mailed at that one, this was likely more of an annoying prank than a serious security breach. Still, just to be sure, you could use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link if you'd like SE to investigate further.

Comment: nationalism is important to me, sad to know that is private to StackExchange

Comment: It is only as private as you make it. You're free to put that information in your profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard He called me a user, a feel like commoner here

Comment: As an official representative?  That seems...somewhat sketchy.  For the cheese contest, I got a pretty good idea who that probably was.

Comment: @KevinB I would like to publish this, I believe it is important for the community

Comment: Well... You put contact details in your profile. So to be honest, such emails are expected, IMO.

Comment: If you want to share, I'd recommend screencapping the email and adding it to your question.  The choice is yours, however.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I honestly can't tell if you're blaming the victim or merely extremely cynical. Just putting contact info out in the world is not the same as an invitation to spam. If you really were only trying to state the fact that there exist people who try to take advantage of others, well, okay I guess, but that doesn't mean people like the OP shouldn't try to seek justice for wrongs that do occur.

Comment: @SOLO not blaming anyone. Just saying I do not consider this as spam. But I do admit being much more liberal than most people on this.

Comment: Nationalism? Do you mean [nationality](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nationality#Noun)? They are not quite the same.

Comment: I still struggle to figure out who in this incident actually is a "fellow commoner" (and what that even is) and who is an "official representative". Was there at any point an SE employee involved (which I highly doubt) or someone claiming to be?

Comment: @ChristianRau A commoner is a member of a community, SE for example.A fellow is a companion, a friendly person. I assume that the message was sent by an individual, not a stuff member of SE.

Answer (score 18):

That's... really weird. Taking your points one at a time:

Although SE staff sometimes contact users via e-mail, they wouldn't do it for something like this.

The numbers on the Mexico/China/Nepal thing don't add up at all, but you surely knew that already.

You are correct, nationality is indeed irrelevant here.

Whining for votes is bad enough, but spamming random users is abusive. There's nothing to be gained by "denouncing" the person publicly here, though. It would just be a spectacle and no Meta SE users can do anything about it. You could [contact the SE team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to let them know about this. 
They might be able to take some action, both because it's spamming and because of the trying-to-game-the-contest thing.

Comment: thanks SOLO, I will go this way